# Box-plot by month in r, remove RA

Tags: r

Im very new in R and I am making a boxplot in R using data collected annually. The questions is about depression and falls in to to this categories: all, most, some, a little, or none of the time. I want to see if there is some correlation between frequency of depression and months of the year.

How do i remove RA?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6j7o.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how do you avoid plotting the NA values try this:

```
ggplot(data %>% filter(!is.na(menthlth)), aes(...)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! When trying this, i got this wronsmessage: "Error in UseMethod("filter_") : no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "function""